# Multiple caption uploads - Rails Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, image, carrierwave

I'm using Rails and Carrierwave to upload multiple images on my app. I'm uploading multiple images using the Active Admin interface and my images are stored as json in my database. I'm now looking to include one caption per image on the app. This means that I may need to upload one image and one caption at a time rather than be able to do multiple uploads as I have done so far for images, which would be very time consuming. I've been searching online and can't seem to find a solution for this and will appreciate any steer.

Is there a way to be able to do multiple image upload and upload all the associated data of the images (including captions) at the same time? If multiple upload of associated data is possible, how would I structure the database so that it's clear what caption relates to which images?

Comment: try to use  csv or xml to populate the multiple image details.you can try Shrine as well.

Comment: Great thank you, will try that!